# Unity. Растягивание грида

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы грид (Tilemap) растягивался в зависимости от размера экрана, и не вылезал за границы?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html

Попробуйте привязать размеры Tilemap к ширине и высоте экрана в каком-нибудь классе Init.

Comment: спасибо. не подскажете, как именно это сделать?